# How to render Custom View from it's instance in android?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-view, android-canvas

I am a web dev and very new to android dev and OOP so I might be making a mistake in how I approach this problem. This seems like a very simple problem.

So I made a custom view called `GridView` that contains a setter function where I can set a `grid` to that class which basically looks like this.

#### GridView.java

```
public class GridView extends View {
    public Grid grid;
    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setGrid(Grid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Then it renders that `grid` on the android canvas with the `onDraw` function.

---

I create an instance of this `GridView` in my android activity so I can use it here. This is basically how that looks.

#### MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public GridView gridView;
    public Grid grid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        grid = new Grid(20, 20);

        gridView = new GridView(this, null);
        gridView.setGrid(grid);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    }
}
```

---

I have listed that `GridView` in the my_activity.xml file like this:

#### my_activity.xml

```
        <view
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            class="com.dev.myapp.GridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

---

### Problem

The problem is that the `grid` variable is null inside the `GridView` class when I create an instance of `GridView` in `MyActivity.java` and pass in the `grid` in the `setGrid` setter function.

However, it works perfectly fine when I create the `grid` instance directly in the `GridView` constructor like this:

#### GridView.java (Working)

```
public class GridView extends View {
    public Grid grid;
    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        grid = new Grid(20, 20);
    }
}
```

---

#### What I think:

I think the problem might be because I am directly rendering the `GridView` class on the `my_activity.xml` file so it is rendering whatever is in that particular file instantly and it is not rendering the instance of that `GridView` that I have created in the `MyActivity.java`.

How am I supposed to render the instance of the `GridView` that I create in `MyActivity.java` on the `my_activity.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML (Depending on IDE this should auto-complete pretty easily)

```
<com.dev.myapp.GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    ... />
```

In your activity code, on `onCreate` for example

```
val gv = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gridView)
gv.setGrid(grid)
```

Comment: This does not work